# How can I make a message from discord into an input on the command prompt on discord.py?

Tags: input, bots, discord.py

I am trying to make a bot use the command user's discord message as an input, but I cant seem to figure it out. I'm still stuck with the command prompt version, (note that I am quite the beginner at this.)

```
Rawdamage=int(input("input damage dealt here. "))
Defense=int(input("input defense of victim here. "))
HP=int(input("input HP of victim."))
Pierce=int(input("input pierce amount here. "))
n = random.randint(1,4)
print(n)
var6= n
var1= Rawdamage
var2= Defense
var3= HP
var4= Pierce
v= 4
V= 3
if (var6==1):
    (var1 - var2 + var4)
    var5= (var1 * v // V)
    print ("damage dealt:")
    print(var5)
    print("hp left:")
    print(var3 - var5)
else:
    var5= (var1 - var2 + var4)
    print("damage dealt:")
    print(var5)
    print("hp left:")
    print(var3 - var5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a signal command with many inputs [Docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#positional) and use the data as follow.

You can call it like this `$game 4 8 21 3` where the order is like this:

- rawdamage
- defense
- hp
- pierce

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="$")

@bot.command()
async def game(ctx, rawdamage: int, defense: int, hp: int, pierce: int):
    n = random.randint(1, 4)
    embed = discord.Embed(title='Fight')
    if n == rawdamage:
        damage_done = rawdamage * 4//3
        embed.add_field(name='Damage dealt', value=damage_done)
        embed.add_field(name='HP left', value=hp-damage_done)

    else:
        damage_done = rawdamage-defense+pierce
        embed.add_field(name='Damage dealt', value=damage_done)
        embed.add_field(name='HP left', value=hp-damage_done)

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

bot.run('TOKEN HERE')
```

Note: please make sure of the math

Comment: This caused a mess up on my side: I got an error loop where they expected an indent at 'from discord.ext import commands' but when I add one, it tells me there's an unexpected indent there...

Comment: Please try it now as is, just add the token and try.

Comment: wait, nevermind, that's just my former mishaps, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Well this isn't a permanent fix, ill edit this for a much better solution when I can remember it, I've done something like this before.

But for now you can just use commands

Here's how they look like:

```
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="Your chosen command prefix")
token = 'Your token'


@client.command()
async def Rawdamage(ctx, *, rawdamage=None):
    var1 = rawdamage

@client.command()
async def Defense(ctx, *, defense=None):
    var2 = defense

@client.command()
async def HP(ctx, *, hp=None):
    var3 = hp

@client.command()
async def Pierce(ctx, *, pierce=None):
    var4 = pierce

@client.command()
async def N(ctx, *, n=None):
    var5 = n
    
    
# Your damage system here #



client.run(token)
```

What this is doing, is that everyytime a message is sent startng with your command prefix, and after the prefix coming one of these commands, the code under it would run.

you see there is also a couple parameters. (ctx, *, rawdamage=None)
ctx mean ctx. And the * means that anything that comes after, will be stored in the rawdamage variable.

So if i did /Rawdamage 10 in discord, your bot would put 10 in var1

Comment: although now that i think of it if your doing a game that would be good for games as then not everything will be stored as input